# Out of memory error at compile time Java 6.0

Tags: java, memory, javac

I know how to use -Xmx -Xms at runtime, is there a way to ask the compiler to allocate more ram.  I have 2 gigs on my pc.  I don't use an IDE just textpad.   I am trying to create a BigInteger with 10,000,000 digits and do operations on it. I tried creating a StringBuffer and ensureCapacity(10000000) and it wont compile.  Is there a class I can use to tell the compiler I need more ram before it compiles, or while it compiles? I did read about RunTime methods and am going to keep multiplying a BigInteger and watch the Heap.  I tried embedding the string into the code "1000000" + etc 10,000,000 digits it wont compile that either.

Comment: What error do you get at compile time?  "won't compile" does not provide enough information.  I wrote a small test program and it compiled with the default heap parameters.

Answer (score 6):

The runtime memory options for javac are not specified using a plain -X flag. Instead use the [-J flag](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) as shown in the following example where the startup memory is reserved to 128M.

```
$javac -J-Xmx128M FooBar.java
```

The option although being a non-standard option is available on both Solaris and Linux, and Windows. Unsure about the Mac.